# Linear Mixed Models non-independent data with unbalanced design and non-independent data?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, independence

I am new in trying to set up a mixed model and I would like some input concerning my model design.

I have been reconstructing the age of some plants and in each year I have been measuring their productivity. So I have a design which includes 580 plants, each plant has an age (varies from 4-25 years) and within each year I have a productivity measurement. I would like to see how the productivity relate to temperature changes.

So with this experimental design I am facing two main problems:

1. Within each plant, the measurements between the years are **non -independent**
2. Each plant has a **different time range** (4 minimum, 25 maxmimum)

I started by trying an LMM model, fitting the variable "plant" as random effect to account for the non-independence of data within each plant.
So my model had the form:

```
model1 <- lmer(Productivity ~ Temperature + (1|Plant), data=data)
```

As a second step I wanted somehow to include the fact that each plant has a different time range … So, I included the factor Year nested in Plant.

So the second model had the form:

```
model2 <-lmer(Productivity ~ Temperature + (1|Plant:Year),  
              data=data)
```

The results between these models are really different, so I am not sure which one better encapsulates my experimental design. I am not quite sure about the nested factor, as Years between plants in some cases coincide …

Answer (score 2):

You say that

> the factor Year nested in Plant

If `Year` is nested within `Plant`. In that case, the moel should be

```
lmer(Productivity~Temperature +(1|Plant/Year),data = data)
```

or eqivalently:

```
lmer(Productivity~Temperature +(1|Plant) + (1|Plant:Year),data = data)
```

So, just to clarify, this means that each `Year` belongs to one and only one `Plant`. So year 1 could belong to plant 1, and year 2 could also belong to plant 1, which means that for each year, one and only 1 plant was measured. For year 3, for example, this could belong to plant 2 (but not plant 1). The nested structure looks like

```
        Plant1             Plant2             Plant3
       /     \            /      \            /     \
    Year1  Year2        Year3  Year4        Year5  Year6
```

---

Edit: It appears from the comments that the design is partially crossed (partially nested). This might look something like

```
        Plant1     Plant2   Plant3
          /\      /  \   \ / \  
         /  \    /    \   X   \         
        /    \  /      \ / \   \
    Year1    Year2   Year3  Year4
```

In that case, the appropriate random structure is:

```
lmer(Productivity~Temperature + (1|Plant) + (1|Year), data = data)
```

More detail about nested and crossed random effects is here:
[Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814)

Comment: Actually the design is not like that exactly.. PLant 1 can have Year 1 and Year 2, but plant 2 can have Year 2 and Year 3 (but not Year 1).. So, some years coincide between plants and some not.. So i am not sure the nested design is the right choice..

Comment: Thanks for the comments, really helpful.. So, a simple diagramm of my design looks like: Plant1 Plant2 Plant3 / \ / \ / \ Year1 Year2 Year2 Year3 Year1 Year3 So after reading a bit, i think is a crossed design and not nested..
Probably a more appropriate code would be:
model3<-lmer(Productivity~Temperature +(1:Plant) +(1|Year), data= data) However, does this model takes into account that within each plant, the yearly measurements are non- indepenedent?

Comment: Yes is does, although if there is structure to the non-independence, such as autocorrelation you may need to use a different package.

Comment: @VictoriaL. Does this answer your question ? If so then please consider marking it as a the accepted answer and (if you haven't already) upvoting it. If not, please could you let us know why so that it can be improved